# Como posso ordenar por tamanho da linha no Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de se ordenar a linha pelo seu tamanho no `Sublime Text`.

Porque eu tenho um código assim:

```
use ArrayAccess;
use ArrayIterator;
use IteratorAggregate;
use Countable;
use Closure;
use JsonSerializable;
use Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

e gostaria de deixá-lo assim, em "um clique" (ou atalho)

```
use Closure;
use Countable;
use ArrayAccess;
use ArrayIterator;
use JsonSerializable;
use IteratorAggregate;
use Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se é uma boa ideia fazer isto, pode parecer bonitinho mas o ideal é ordenar por relevância de uso. Mas se quer mesmo achei um [código no fórum deles](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9603#p38209):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import sort

def line_length_sort(txt):
    txt.sort(lambda a, b: cmp(len(a), len(b)))
    return txt

class SortLinesLengthCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, reverse=False,
                        remove_duplicates=False):
        view = self.view

        sort.permute_lines(line_length_sort, view, edit)

        if reverse:
            sort.permute_lines(sort.reverse_list, view, edit)

        if remove_duplicates:
            sort.permute_lines(sort.uniquealise_list, view, edit)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/SublimePlugin.py).

Também tem [plugin pronto](https://github.com/Doi9t/SortBy).

Comment: Bigwon, eu querio isso por ser o padrão de codificação do `Laravel 4`. Pode observar nesse código da classe [Illuminate\Support\Collection])(https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Collection.php)

Comment: Quando você diz que "não é uma boa idéia... ordenar por relevância de uso", você está falando especifiamente dos namespaces, né?

Comment: Sim, claro. Nesse exemplo nem bagunçou mas tem caso que poderia ter ficado pior.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um plugin que você pode adicionar no `sublime-text`: 
[SortBy - Github](https://github.com/Doi9t/SortBy)